# Remove "\n\r" and some whitespaces in wp_ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Trying to find out where `\r \n` and white spaces are adding to response in ajax call of WP_ajax.

**PHP Code:**

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_checkExists', 'checkExists');
function checkExists(){
    $textValue=isset($_POST['textValue'])?$_POST['textValue']:'';
    $tablename=isset($_POST['tablename'])?$_POST['tablename']:'';
    $table_name=$GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix.$tablename;
    $tableColumn=isset($_POST['tablecolumn'])?$_POST['tablecolumn']:'';
    $results=$GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results('select id from '.$table_name.' where '.$tableColumn.' = "'.$textValue.'" ',OBJECT);
    echo $results[0]->id;
    die; 
}
```

In php `echo` I will get only Id. Other than that nothing is prefixing.

**jQuery code:**

```js
function checkExists(tablename,name,tablecolumn){
jQuery('#existedValue'+tablename).val('');

textValue=jQuery("#"+name).val();
var action;
if('group'==tablename || 'semester'==tablename)
{
    action='checkExists';
}

if('course'==tablename || "subject"==tablename){
    action='checkExistsProgram';
}

jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
            'action':action,
            'textValue':textValue,
            'tablecolumn':tablecolumn,
            'tablename':tablename

        },
        function (response){

            if(response=="")
            {   

                if(tablename=='group')
                {
                    jQuery('#existedValueGroup').val('0');
                    addGroup();
                }
                else if(tablename=='semester'){
                    jQuery('#existedValueSemester').val('0')
                    addSemester();

                }
                else if(tablename=='course'){
                    jQuery('#existedValueCourse').val('0')
                    addCourse();
                }
                else if(tablename=='subject'){
                    jQuery('#existedValueSubject').val('0')
                    addSubject();
                }
                jQuery('#alertmessage').html("");       

            }else{
                jQuery('#alertmessage').html("Already Existed, Please enter other").css({"color":"red","display":"block"}).animate({'opacity':0},5000);
                jQuery('#existedValueGroup').val('');
                jQuery('#existedValueSemester').val('');
                jQuery('#existedValueCourse').val('');
            }   
        }
        );
}
```

In jQuery ajax response I am getting `\r\n  [output]`.
`[output]` is the response I have mentioned for understanding purpose only.

Now, in console of ajax response has `\r\n  [output]`. What could be the possible reason for this.

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: please post your wordpress code.

Comment: Finally I got answer, It is the problem with PHP pages, There at the end of page, I removed new lines and spaces. It  worked fine.